# Tricky Multi-Variable Limit

Tags: limits

I am trying to show that the limit of the function $f(x,y,z) = \dfrac{x^2y}{x^3+y^2+z^2}$ is $0$ as $(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)$ using the squeeze theorem and I am having a lot of difficult finding an algebraic expression that the absolute value of $f(x,y,z)$ is smaller than whose limit goes to $0$. Any tips or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about the path $(x(t),y(t),z(t)) = (-t^{0.2}, t , t^{0.3})$? Then we have $f(x(t),y(t),z(t)) = f(t) = \frac{ t^{1.4}}{t^2} = t^{-0.6}$, and as $t \to 0$, we have $f(t) \to \infty$.

Comment: Do you perhaps intend to have $x^2+y^2+z^2$ for your denominator? Then it really is a straightforward squeeze argument (and the $0$ is correct).

Comment: No unfortunately I do not, in fact my original function I was working with was f(x,y,z) = (x^2ycos(z))/(x^3+y^2+z^2). I am assuming the limit was zero because I looked it up on wolfram alpha, but perhaps I am mistaken.

Comment: This function won't be defined everywhere near the origin, as you can choose $x^3=-(y^2+z^2)$. So there can't be a limit. Don't trust wolfram alpha.

Comment: Hint: A good student of mathematics will seldom look at Wolfram.

Comment: Ok fair enough I suppose now I have to find two different limits then thanks for the advice.

Comment: I'm saying that your definition of limit requires that the function make sense (be defined) in some region around the origin (but not necessarily at the origin). This function violates that.